# How to kill the all intentservices and services in an application?

Tags: android

I would like to kill the all services in my application properly,

killBackgroundProcesses is not working for mine

please drop your  answer if you know the solution

Comment: Call `stopService()` on each of them. Done.

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

first get list of all running services

```
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
  String serv = service.service.getClassName();
nbStopRunningService(getApplicationContext(),serv);
}
```

After getting individual service kill it.
use this lib

```
 compile 'com.github.nikhilborad:basehelp:1.02'
```